# VBA Customize scrollbar with UserForm variables

Tags: excel, scrollbar, userform, vba

Being new to VBA, I'm trying to add a customized scrollbar to my sheet. By customized I mean I can decide the min value, max value and smallchange of the scrollbar using a Userform where I asked the wanted values. So far I've stored the values in public variables following : 
[screen of the Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3uP2.jpg)

```
Option Explicit

Public A As Integer
Public B As Integer
Public C As Integer


Private Sub Valider_Click()

If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
    A = TextBox1.Value
    Unload Me
Else
    MsgBox "Valeur mimimale incorrecte"
End If

If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    B = TextBox2.Value
    Unload Me
Else
    MsgBox "Valeur maximale incorrecte"
End If

If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
    C = TextBox3.Value
    Unload Me
Else 
    MsgBox "Pas incorrect"
End If

MsgBox A & " " & B & " " & C

End Sub
```

and I just reassigned the values for ".Min", ".Max" and ".SmallChange." with A,B and C in the defaut scrollbar code given by Excel :

```
Sub curseur()

ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(180, 45.75, 119.25, 13.5).Select
With Selection
    .Value = 0
    .Min = A
    .Max = B
    .SmallChange = C
    .LargeChange = 10
    .LinkedCell = "$G$4"
    .Display3DShading = True
End With
Range("F4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/100"
Range("G4").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
End With
End Sub
```

So I have 3 textboxes and one Commandbutton ("Valider"). Basically my idea is to fulfill those 3 boxes with the forementionned values (min, max,...) and store them in public variables. For the moment I'm just running my code from the developper tab using F5.

I'm first running the userform. Once the textboxes are fulfilled and the CommandButton pressed, the MessageBox returns the values contained in the variables A,B and C.
Then I want to use those to "define" my scrollbar. When I press F5, The scrollbar is showing itself (see screenshot) but if I go to the properties all values are set to zero. Seems I'm not calling the variables A,B,C the right way : [scrollbar properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3C2t.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly is happening and what is missing? Do you have one form with multiple textboxes? Because you are unloading after first check. what does your msgbox say? How and when are you calling your code? Please add some details to help us help. I cant't see how you are forwarding the parameters for your scrollbars...

Comment: I edited my post adding 2 screenshots and more detailed explainations. Does it help ? (I'm sorry, since I'm new to this, I'm not sure which information you need. But that's pretty much all taht is to my code here). Thanks for your help btw !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your second sub (curseur) doesn't know what values you assigned from your form. Variables are 'destroyed' after last bit of your code ends. So variables A, B, C in curseur() have no value.

If you add the call of the procedure to the end of your valider_click sub this should fix your problem. You should exit your sub before if your values aren't numeric:

```
Private Sub Valider_Click()

    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
        A = TextBox1.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Valeur mimimale incorrecte"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
        B = TextBox2.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Valeur maximale incorrecte"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If IsNumeric(TextBox3.Value) Then
        C = TextBox3.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Pas incorrect"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox A & " " & B & " " & C
    Call curseur
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again. But there's still a hitch somewhere... The call of my sub "curseur" is working fine (I just had to write "curseur.curseur" since my Sub is in a Module call "curseur"... I'm progressivley getting familiar with hierarchy). I'm still on it but if you have an idea, thanks in advance

Comment: I had it working calling the variables A,B and C as variables from the userform. Id est : ".Min = userform1.A". Does it make sens ?

Comment: Probably the best would be to declare your sub as `Sub curseur(A as INteger, B as Integer, C as Integer)` and change the call to `Call curseur(A, B, C)`. In nearly every situation it is better to call with parameters instead of declaring and using global variables.